# Definite article for a particular purpose that's more important than individual place or its location

Tags: definite-article

My English grammar book says "the" is common with places that we go to for a particular purpose (that is more important than the individual place or its location), so we go to the petrol station (to fill up our cars) or to the pub (for a drink).

Store, shop, gym, post office. Are these places for a particular purpose also? Although there is more than one of stores, shops, we use "the?" Do these places provide a service and so use "the".

Comment: The practical meaning of "going to the supermarket" is "going shopping for food" (the activity). Same with "needed to go into the hospital" (in AmE), where it means "needed to be hospitalized". It doesn't refer to a particular hospital or supermarket (as you correctly surmised) but to the purpose the place serves.  **the** in these uses is generic.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice The point is we're thinking more of activity rather than the place itself, right? What about "bank"? If the person with whom you're speaking has no idea which bank you're talking about, would you say *go to **the** bank*?

Comment: Yes, you're saying, in effect, that you need to do some banking. You're not referring to particular bank -- not unless there's only one bank in town :-)

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice `The heart pumps blood around the body`. Why is there "the" in "heart" and "body"?

Comment: Because these nouns are being referred to *generically*.  It's not a particular body and a particular heart.   Much like "I need to go to the bank".  Not a particular bank, but "the bank" as exemplar of any and all banks, a place where you do banking.

Comment: You are basically repeating this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345167/go-to-the-supermarket-shops These are basically a type of place that is considered specific. It contrasts with other specific places where specific functions take place.

Comment: @Lambie actually, my confusion is when I know which place I'm going to, the listener, however, doesn't know exactly which one I'm referring to. In this case, do we still use *the* or use *a*?

Comment: Look at FF's comment under James K's answer.

Comment: @Nyambek There's no rule. Habitual use pushes it toward "the." Referring to a place because of its function pushes it towards "the." Using a broader category of place pushes it toward "a," for example "I'm going to a government building" vs "I'm going to the license bureau."

Answer (score 2):

It would be common to use "the" in those contexts.

"I'm going to the post office" or "to the gym" are perfectly correct.

"I'm going to the shops" would be more common (as you would probably be visiting multiple shops for the particular purpose of shopping".  But if you doing a particular type of shopping, you could say "I'm going to the supermarket" or "the hardware store", for example.

So:

- The shops  *There is usually only one collection of shops in a town*. You say "the shops" because they are the shops you usually go to, for the particular purpose of shopping.
- The pub. *Many people will habitually visit one pub, even if there are more than one pub in the town*.
- The bank. *Again, a town may have several banks, but I only use one of them.
- The supermarket. *Many towns only have one, even if there are several, I'll normally only visit one of them regularly.*
- The cinema *Only the largest cities have more than one cinema*.

But if the reference isn't clear you'd be less likely to use the.

- The petrol station.
- The shop *Contrast this with "the shops".
- The house
- The cafe

If from your personal context any of these could be specifically understood you can use "the". If a village only has one shop then "the shop" is understood.  If you and a friend meet at a particular cafe after work each day then "the cafe" is understood.  If you are talking to your housemate and you talk about "the house" the identity is understood.

Now suppose you are at a petrol station, and there are several in the town, all of which you use equally, and your friend asks you where you are.  You *don't* say "I'm at the petrol station." Since that doesn't answer the question.  You might say "I'm at the petrol station on Oak street", or "The petrol station by the supermarket". By saying "by the supermarket" you identify the station, so you use "the petrol station".  Or you cooperatively understand that your friend doesn't really want to know *where* you are but *why* you aren't with them, so you might reply "I'm getting petrol".

Comment: So the individual place or its location is not important in this context, right? We're thinking more of activity rathen the place itself although the listener doesn't know a place which I mean in. Am I right?

Comment: You could be speaking on the phone to a friend who's never been to the place where you now live. If he asks about your social life, you might say *"I go down the pub once or twice a week"*. He doesn't know ***which*** pub you're talking about, obviously. But he will probably understand that you mean ***a local pub*** - which isn't necessarily the *nearest* pub, but obviously it's ***the pub you usually go to.*** If you said *I go to **a** pub once or twice a week*, he'd probably assume that you went to ***different*** pubs (not always the same one, you don't have your own particular "local").

Comment: @FumbleFingers What about places such as "store", "market", "gym", "book store"? Is it the same as your explanation above? Which means local store/market/gym/book store eventhough the person I'm speaking to doesn't know which of them I'm talkikg about.

Comment: Exactly that.  I'm going to the gym = the gym that I usually go to.  So "I'm going to the store" is less common for people in a town (with many shops) but perhaps in a village (with one village store) it would make sense. It is culturally common to go to the same pub, and the same gym.  But not so much for "book store"  But in a university context (in which there is a university book shop) this may be more likely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If there is more than one pub or other such places, do we still use "the"?

Comment: "It is culturally common to go to **the** same pub, and **the** same gym."

Comment: @FumbleFingers What about cinema? Do we use "the" or "a?" I'm going to the/a cinema.

Comment: It's [almost always "the" cinema.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=going+to+a+cinema%2Cgoing+to+the+cinema&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Even if people or I routinely go to several different petrol stations. Do you still use "the?"

Comment: Everything I have to say about this usage has already been said.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In my town there is several petrol stations in the street. If my friend asks, where are you? I'm at the petrol station. Clearly, my friend will ask to me, where is it? Should I use "a" here? Or the listener doesn't neccessarily know which petrol station I'm talking about, then use "the". What do you think?

Comment: If it's unlikely your friend knows which one you mean, *and* you personally aren't that committed to always using the same one, you probably wouldn't use ***the***. In all other cases, I don't think it makes a blind bit of difference. You can't seriously believe ordinary speakers care much - you must be able to find countless instances of both articles, so you know they're both "normal". Even if there's a difference according to some speakers, in any *specific* contexts, I don't think you will enhance your understanding of English by these lines of inquiry.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. Why do you say "the shops"? Why not say "shops? I'm going to the shops. Does it mean shops I usually go to. "The" is used.

Comment: @Nyambek Why do you keep asking the same question when FF answered this in his second comment?? And a later comment.